# Error Crud update Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Alguien me ayuda con este error que me tiene ya con dolor de cabeza por favor

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Parte del **Controlador** del Update :

```
 public function edit($id)
{
   return view("almacen.categoria.edit",["categoria"=>Categoria::findOrFail($id)]);

}
public function update(CategoriaFormRequest $request,$id)
{
    $categoria=Categoria::findOrFail($id);
    $categoria->nombre=$request->get('nombre');
    $categoria->descripcion=$request->get('descripcion');
    $categoria->update();
    return Redirect::to('almacen/categoria');
}
```

La **vista** del Update :

```
@extends ('layouts.admin')
@section ('contenido')
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <h3>Editar Categoría: {{ $categoria->nombre}}</h3>
        @if (count($errors)>0)
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{$error}}</li>
            @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
        @endif

        {!!Form::model($categoria,['method'=>'PATCH','route'=>['almacen.categoria.update',$categoria->idcategoria]])!!}
        {{Form::token()}}
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
            <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control" value="{{$categoria->nombre}}" placeholder="Nombre...">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="descripcion">Descripción</label>
            <input type="text" name="descripcion" class="form-control" value="{{$categoria->descripcion}}" placeholder="Descripción...">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Guardar</button>
            <button class="btn btn-danger" type="reset">Cancelar</button>
        </div>

        {!!Form::close()!!}     

    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

---

Imagen de la tabla categoria...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Haz un var_dump($_POST) en tu controlador para ver que te envia el formulario.

Comment: Estas seguro que existe la columna id en la tabla de categorias?

Comment: Coloca el modelo de tu base de datos o de la tabla categorias.

Comment: Muestra tu modelo y la tabla categoria. Básicamente te dice que no existe una columna `id` en la tabla categoria

Comment: No existe id en la tabla categorias

Comment: Utiliza el enlace editar en tu pregunta para añadir información adicional. Tu publicación como respuesta, se agrego como edición a tu respuesta. @Javier

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tu clave principal se llama idcategoria no se llama id!
Establece en el modelo:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'idcategoria';
```

Saludos

Comment: Fijate en la query de la imagen. Esta haciendo where `categoria`.ìd` cuando id no existe en la db. Debe ser where `categoria`.ìdcategoria`, por lo que debe establecer protected $primaryKey = 'idcategoria'; en el modelo

Answer (score -1):

Estimado cambialo por este valor

```
{!!Form::model($categoria,['method'=>'PATCH','route'=>['categoria.update',$categoria->idcategoria]])!!}
```

Comment: no solo es poner código, explica el por que esto da solución al problema; sobre todo por que si revisas ya hay una respuesta marcada como aceptada, señal de que el problema fue resuelto

Comment: Se aplaude la intención de responder. Sin embargo, una respuesta con solo código es demasiado escueta y me temo que no cumple con los estándares de calidad de StackOverflow. Te invito a leer [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Te invito a editar tu respuesta y explicar por qué o cómo esto resuelve el problema del OP.